# How to pass a parameter of type List for web api beyond Model (ASPNET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, restful-url

I have to pass a list to my method of WEB API along with the model?

Here is the line of my application that calls the method to add a posting, I would be able to send beyond the model, another parameter of type list

```
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/LancamentoReceitaDespesa/AddLancamentoParcelar/", lancamentoReceitaDespesa).Result;
```

My method of web api that will receive the parameters:

```
    // POST api/LancamentoReceitaDespesa 
    [ActionName("AddLancamentoParcelar")]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostAddLancamentoParcelar(LancamentoReceitaDespesa lancamentoReceitaDespesa)
    {


         return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    }
```

Comment: Do you want to post two parameters, am I right?

Comment: That's it! beyond the model wanted to send a list<string>

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the easiest way is do as follows:

```
//model
public class LancamentoReceitaDespesaRequest
{
    public LancamentoReceitaDespesa LancamentoReceitaDespesa {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<string> Mensagens {get;set;}
}


// POST api/LancamentoReceitaDespesa 
[ActionName("AddLancamentoParcelar")]
public HttpResponseMessage PostAddLancamentoParcelar(LancamentoReceitaDespesaRequest lancamentoReceitaDespesaRequest)
{
     return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```